# React dropdown select not changing defaultValue after applying filter

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I populate my trip booking list with some data from the DB and it contains a select/dropdown menu with payment options in every list item.

I use this dropdown to edit corresponding user payment method. It works fine and defaultValue is populated correctly with user's payment method from the DB.

So, I have another dropdown at the top to filter users by name, date, etc. What happens is that when I apply the filter, selecting a name, my defaultValues remain the same of the initial names on the list before applying the filter. They don't keep their original values.

For example: my list have 10 results. If I select a user name that will have 4 bookings, the 4 bookings will keep the defaultValues of the firts 4 users before applying the filter.

Top filters:

```
const handleFilterByUser = (e: any) => {
   setUser(e.target.value);
}

...

<div className="mt-12 w-full">
  <p className="text-sm">Filters</p>
  <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center sm:justify-start gap-2 mt-4 w-full">
    <select
      className="w-fit max-w-full border border-zinc-300 p-2"
      onChange={(e) => handleFilterByDate(e)}
    >
      <option value="" key="0">
        Booking date
      </option>
      {bookingDates.map((date, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={date.date}>
          {date.date}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
    <select
      className="w-fit max-w-full border border-zinc-300 p-2"
      onChange={(e) => handleFilterByUser(e)}
    >
      <option value="" key="0">
        Booked by
      </option>
      {users.map((user, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={user.username}>
          {user.username}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
    <select
      className="w-fit max-w-full border border-zinc-300 p-2"
      onChange={(e) => handleFilterByTitle(e)}
    >
      <option value="" key="0">
        Trip title
      </option>
      {titles.map((title, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={title.title}>
          {title.title}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>;
```

List results:

```
{
    openBookingList && booking.filter((booking) => {

        if (dates === "" && user === "" && title === "") {
            return booking;
        } else {

            if (dates !== "" && booking.date.toLowerCase().includes(dates.toLowerCase())) {
                return booking
            }

            if (user !== "" && booking.username.toLowerCase().includes(user.toLowerCase())) {
                return booking
            }

            if (title !== "" && booking.title.toLowerCase().includes(title.toLowerCase())) {
                return booking
            }
        }

    }).map((booking, index) => (

    <div key={index} className="flex flex-col">
        
        <p className="text-blue-600 text-xs">Booked by:<span className="text-blue-900 font-bold"> {booking.username}</span></p>

        // ...

      <div>
        <select
            className="px-1 border border-zinc-300 text-xs text-blue-900 font-semibold bg-white"
            id={`method${booking.bookingID}`}
            defaultValue={booking.paymentMethod}
            onChange={(e) => {setPaymentMethod(booking.bookingID, e.target.value);}}
        >
        
           <option value="cash"> Cash </option>
           <option value="cc_installments"> Credit Card </option>
           <option value="in_installments"> Other </option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    ))
}
```

I tried using `value` instead of `defaultValue` and change its `state` but I don't know how to load its initial value "booking.paymentMethod" outside `map()` looping.